# Securing Flask-Restful API with OAuth2

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, flask-restful

Okay, so I wrote an API using Flask-Restful and now I want to implement OAuth2 authorization.

I've tried [pyoauth2](https://github.com/StartTheShift/pyoauth2), but it's undocumented and the [tutorial](http://tech.shift.com/post/39516330935/implementing-a-python-oauth-2-0-provider-part-1) is quite complicated.

So, my question is: How do I do that?

Comment: Update: I'm currently using [Flask-OAuthlib](https://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/), but it doesn't play well with Flask-Restful, so I had to port my entire API to vanilla Flask (luckily it wasn't that big). Maybe there is a way, though -- looking into this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Follow the flask-oauthlib guide to get a basic endpoint set up. Ensure that it works with a vanilla flask endpoint.
2. Configure your API to use the oauth decorator.

   ```
   oauth = OAuth2Provider(app)
   api = restful.Api(app, decorators=[oauth.require_oauth('email')])
   ```

Comment: Wow, seems super easy. Thanks!