# How to secure Flask-RESTPlus API with oAuth2?

Tags: flask, oauth-2.0, flask-restplus

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875211/securing-flask-restful-api-with-oauth2).

My goal is the same, but the answer given there uses a library that appears to have been superseded by Authlib. Does Authlib expose a similar decorator I could import? Can anyone link me to a solution or documentation on this? (I couldn't find anything listed in Authlib).

If anyone has any other solutions, I'd love to hear them. How do I use OAuth2 with a Flask-RESTPlus API?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [RFC6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) implementation.

Authlib implements this using `ResourceProtector` and `BearerTokenValidator`. You can call `ResourceProtector()` to return a `require_oauth` decorator to protect your resources.

See this link [Resource Server](https://docs.authlib.org/en/stable/specs/rfc6750.html).

If your are not managing the tokens, but using a 3rd party authentication server, then you can use [introspection-in-resource-server](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/specs/rfc7662.html#use-introspection-in-resource-server).

*In case you want to add "authentication", there are also other libraries which can simplify further the token management based on OpenID Connect, see [FLAAT](https://github.com/indigo-dc/flaat).*